# Hide an image on mobile website?

Tags: html, css, image

I can't seem to hide the #right  image on my iPhone. I want it to display on my webbrowser, but not on small phones.

*Edit* I've tried `visibility: hidden !important;`
I've tried `screen and`
I've tried `display: none`
I've tried hiding by class name

Thanks!

```
   <html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    http-equiv="content-type">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
</head>
<style> 
    html {
    width: 470px;
    height: 725px;
  }
  div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 75px;
    width: 70%;
  }
  #left {
    width: 300px;
    height: 700px;

  }
  #right {
     position: absolute;
     width: 300px;
     height: 700px;
     right: 10px;
     z-index: -1;
  }
  #title {
    position: absolute;  
    top: 10px;
    left: 31%;
    width: 330px;
    height: 90px;

  }
  #rightP {
        position: absolute;  
    width: 75%;
    left:30px;
  }
  #cross {
        position: absolute;  
        top: 610px;
        left: 48%;

        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
  }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   #right{ 
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
    }
   .mobile-hide {
     display: none;
     visibility: hidden;
   }

 }

  body {
        min-width: 300px;

    background-color: #f1e2c1;
  }
</style> 
<body  link="#000000" vlink="#808080" alink="#FF0000">
  <img id="title" src="images/title.jpg"> 
    <img id="left" src="images/left.jpg">
    <img class="mobile-hide" id="right" src="images/right.jpg">
    <div>
        <p > 


    </p>
    </div>
  <img id="cross" src="images/cross.jpg"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's `display: none`, not `display: hidden`.

Comment: For future reference, you should narrow down your code to just the bit that's relevant to the problem. This is why StackOverflow told you about context. I've edited your question to remove all of the unnecessary stuff, leaving only the bit that's actually supposed to hide the image.

Comment: I've tried display: none still didnt work. I put all the context back in because I'm sure some of it is relevant. This problem is very strange...

Comment: Can you try visiting your website as incognito? The website's css might be cached on your mobile browser and you are still seeing the old one.

Comment: Tried it with a fresh install of chrome on iPhone 6. still no dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code of the stylesheet on your website, you have this line above your media queries:

```
//small screen sizes
```

`//` is NOT to be used for CSS comments ( but only in PHP and JS)! In fact, this messes up your code, since the browser thinks it's some kind of CSS and can't handle it (and all the other code following it).

So just change that line to

```
/*small screen sizes*/
```

and it will work.

Comment: Hmm I added your changes. Are you saying when you visit this site: https://mtgparley.github.io./ on your mobile phone you only see the left image? For me I see the left and right image...

Comment: I knew it was something dumb like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you not to use id's while using css as classes tend to do all the work required without that level of specificity, for this example all you need to do is switch the display with visibility

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #right { 
       visibility: hidden !important;
    }
  }
```

Hope This helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add a media query for that specific element, or create a class called `mobHide` and create something like the following

Element

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #right { 
       display: none !important;
    }
  }
```

Class Specific - Apply `.mobHide` class to anything you want removing on mobile devices.

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .mobHide{ 
       display: none !important;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my code in the question, but still no luck